# Can I use operators of the form $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+i\frac{d}{dx}$ inside NDEigensystem?

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, finite-element-method

I am currently trying to find the eigenfunctions of Hamiltonians of the form $\hat H=\frac12 \hat p^2 +a\hat p +f(\hat x)$, and I thought I would give [`NDEigensystem`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDEigensystem.html) a try, since it is easily the most accessible tool in the Mathematica toolbox for this task.

For example, `NDEigensystem` handles the harmonic oscillator perfectly well,

```
NDEigensystem[
 -1/2 ψ''[x] + 1/2 x^2 ψ[x]
 , ψ, {x, -15, 15}, 5
 ]
```

and it also works perfectly fine if I introduce a non-Hermitian first-order derivative into the operator,

```
NDEigensystem[
 -1/2 ψ''[x] + 0.15 ψ'[x] + 1/2 x^2 ψ[x]
 , ψ, {x, -15, 15}, 5
 ]
```

but if I try and give that derivative an imaginary coefficient, as

```
NDEigensystem[
 -1/2 ψ''[x] + 0.15 I ψ'[x] + 1/2 x^2 ψ[x]
 , ψ, {x, -15, 15}, 5
 ]
```

it goes completely belly-up: it returns nonsense eigenfunctions, and it throws the inscrutable error message

```
NDEigensystem::femdpop: -- Message text not found -- (NDSolve`FEM`FEMStiffnessElements) >>
```

Is it possible to use operators like this one with this function? (Ideally, I'd also go up to operators like $\hat x \hat p+\hat p\hat x$.) If so, how can I do it? If not, is there some equivalently simple way with built-in functions or otherwise?

Comment: What Mathematica version are you using? I do not get the message you posted when I [try your code](http://i.imgur.com/nfZ9COV.png).

Comment: @Anton I'm on 10.3 on this machine. Maybe that's the cue to update, then. To the eigenfunctions look reasonable there?

Comment: And you should buy a Mac if you are not using one :). As for the the eigenfunctions check, I have to look into more detail (later...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In version 10.4.1 the support for complex valued PDEs to be solved via FEM has been improved. So this works in 10.4.1:

```
res = NDEigensystem[-1/2 \[Psi]''[x] + 0.15 I \[Psi]'[x] + 
    1/2 x^2 \[Psi][x], \[Psi], {x, -15, 15}, 5];
res[[1]]
{0.49806057220719635` + 4.192136700091489`*^-15 I, 
 1.494775497407078` + 7.331246737662917`*^-15 I, 
 2.688987707562188` + 3.703438331133301`*^-15 I, 
 3.6133943321857105` - 1.4211236798915415`*^-15 I, 
 4.993737608506491` + 3.284855566663262`*^-15 I}
```

Comment: Indeed, so it seems, and on 10.4.0 also. It's hard to wrap one's head around the surprising amount of stuff that changes on the "point" updates on v10 (e.g. [this other example](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/117940/1000), or [ReIm on v10.1](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReIm.html)).

Comment: I posted on math.stackexchange a request for an introduction to the underlying mathematics of complex valued PDE's at the undergraduate level, possibly with applications.  See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1849283/request-for-introduction-to-complex-valued-pdes-and-their-applications-in-math for details.  Thanks.